# mask part of image in css

Tags: html, css

I want the part of this man's head to be out of the circle and the text on the image to be masked in the circle (only the head is out and the rest is masked in the circle) This is my code
What changes are needed?

[image: my ui]

```css
.manbox {
  width: 100%;
}

#circle {
  background: #660099;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#man {
  border-radius: 171px;
  margin: auto;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#man>img {
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="manbox">
  <div id="circle">
    <div id="man">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cJvFkv3/man.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text wouldn't fit inside the circle, but people usually make pictures that have all of that.

Comment: @ali I remove some of your unnecessary css and came up of the image you want i added the 2 circles as well. check the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way putting a border-radius on the image itself. remove unnecessary css and just combine them in one ID. Let me know

```css
.manbox {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left:100px;

}

#circle {
  background: #660099;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top:50px;
  position:absolute;
 
}

#mytext {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px gray;
}

#mytext1 {
  font-size:20px;
  height: auto;
  background-color:white;
  max-width:200px;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100px;
  right:-50px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px gray;
}


#smallcircle {
  background: #660099;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float:right;
}

#mediumcircle {
  background: #660099;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float:right;
  margin-top:-40px;
}




#circle>img {
  border-radius:50%;  
  object-fit:contain;
  width:100%;
  height:330px;
  margin-top:-29px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="manbox">
  <div id="circle">
          
       <div id="mytext">here for all your text</div>
       <div id="mytext1">here for all your text</div>
       
       <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cJvFkv3/man.png" alt="">    

       <div id="mediumcircle"></div>
       <div id="smallcircle"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```